# Posting to Database without <form> tags in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering if there is a simple and safe way to insert values from an input field into a wordpress database without form tags. As I have it, I used the following:

```
<input id="amountSlider" type="range" min="100000" value="200000" max="1000000" required="required" step="1000" />
<input type="text" id="emailText"/>

<button id="inputSubmit" onClick="checkSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

and

```
function checkSubmit() {
    var userInfo = {
            'Amount': document.getElementById('amountSlider').value,
            'emailOf': document.getElementById('emailText').value
    };
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "wp-admin/submitInfo.php",
                type: "POST",  
                data: userInfo,    
                success: function (html) {             
                    if (html==1) {                 
                    alert('ok.');
                    } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
                            }      
            });
    }
```

Is it possible without a form tag?

form tag meaning:

```
<form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Its possible.

```
<input id="amountSlider" type="range" min="100000" value="200000" max="1000000" required="required" step="1000" />
<input type="text" id="emailText"/>

<button id="inputSubmit">Submit</button>


jQuery('#inputSubmit').on('click', function () {
    var userInfo = {
        amount: jQuery('#amountSlider').val(),
        emailOf: jQuery('#emailText').val()
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "wp-admin/submitInfo.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: userInfo,
        success: function (html) {
            if (html == 1) {
                alert('ok.');
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But place your file in wp-admin/ catalog - is bad idea. Use `wp_ajax_{action}` hooks for this.

Comment: How do I do that?